# Problema con datos del GPS 303G

Tags: php, servidor, ip, gps

Tengo un gps 303g ya configurado y enviando la señal con la información a la app que viene por defecto con él.
Lo que deseo es obtener esos datos que se envían ya sea en un servidor o una base de datos, pero no sé como lograr que el gps mande la información y como acceder a ella.

Si alguno tiene información al respecto le agradecería.

Comment: Debes investigar con los fabricantes del GPS y/o con los desarrolladores de la App, si ofrecen esa posibilidad. Si no la ofrecen, entonces tendrás que programar una App que recoja la información que el GPS emite y la traslade a tu base de datos. Las preguntas que plantees aquí deben estar basadas en un problema concreto sobre el código. Supongamos que tienes que crear tú la App, pues si hay algún problema creando **ese** código, entonces puedes preguntar aquí y te ayudaremos a resolver **ese** problema, pero no a decidir sobre herramientas a usar.

Comment: Es precisamente ese el problema, el fabricante me ofrece una app, pero yo quiero desarrollar mi propia app, el problema es que desconozco totalmente como conectar los datos, no sé como hacer que los datos del gps lleguen a mi servidor o a mi BD.

Comment: Desde aquí no te diremos cómo hacer una App, en cambio, si hay algún problema con el código sí te ayudaremos. Te toca a ti decidir de qué forma vas a recoger los datos que emite el GPS, para luego transferirlos a una base de datos. ¿Qué herramientas se usarán para eso? Te toca a ti decidirlo.